# When starting session in appium recieving error:

Tags: android-studio, appium

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home ' must exist

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check if `JAVA_HOME` is being configured on your local machine?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home  I got this output

Comment: i also trying to start another session and getting this An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at 'Downloads/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk' does not exist or is not accessible with this json {
  "platformName": "Android",
  "automationName": "UIAutomator2",
  "udid": "emulator-5554",
  "appPackage": "com.wdiodemoapp",
  "appActivity": ".MainActivity ",
  "app": "Downloads/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk"
}

Comment: Please check if your apk under test exists at `Downloads/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk` and then please try again with your full apk path from home folder like,
`/Users/<USER-PROFILE>/Downloads/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk`

Comment: Is it resolved? @Sergei

Comment: Nope, i tried, same thing

Comment: Can you please post your complete json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240326/discussion-between-bipin-kumar-chaurasia-and-sergei).

Comment: @Sergei Is this issue resolved for you? If yes, can you please share your answer here